# aspell - special characters and math mode

Tags: math-mode, spelling

1) How can I make `aspell` cope with words containing special characters like `F\"orster` or `\AA ngstrom`? I can't simply add these to the dictionary.

2) How can I make `aspell` skip math mode? For example, in `$a^bc$` it offers to replace `bc`.

Comment: If you don't have valid reasons to stick to the old and ugly input method you should consider switching to unicode and use utf-8 instead. Your spell checker will embrace the decision as well.

Comment: Thanks, utf-8 works fine (I'm relatively new to latex). But the other thing about skipping math mode is still a bummer..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[GNU Aspell](http://aspell.net) comes with a dedicated TeX/LaTeX filter which can be activated with the `--mode=tex` command-line option. The functionality of this filter is, however, still limited. In essence, when Aspell is in TeX/LaTeX mode it skips control sequences and checks/ignores macro arguments according to a list of macro signatures which can be extended on the command line or in one of Aspell’s configuration files. Moreover, when in TeX/LaTeX mode, Aspell skips comments by default. Check out the [Aspell manual](http://aspell.net/man-html/Notes-on-Various-Filters-and-Filter-Modes.html#Notes-on-Various-Filters-and-Filter-Modes) for the details.

Aspell is presently not able to handle words containing special characters given in traditional ASCII notation such as `F\"orster` even though improving Aspell in this direction is a prominent item in the [Aspell TODO list](http://aspell.net/man-html/Important-Items.html#Important-Items). Furthermore, it is not possible to tell Aspell to skip specific regions such as in-line formulae or selected LaTeX environments.

As for the latter issue, a capable front-end to Aspell might come to your rescue. An example is – what a surprise ;-) – the Emacs text editor. In fact, when Emacs visits a TeX/LaTeX input file the spellchecker (which can be customized to use Aspell as back-end by setting `ispell-program-name` appropriately) skips all regions matching the regular expressions specified in `ispell-tex-skip-alists`. By default, in-line formulae are not skipped, though. In order for this to happen, you have to extend `ispell-tex-skip-alists` in your Emacs initialization file, e.g. using the following form:

```lisp
(setcar ispell-tex-skip-alists
        (append
         (car ispell-tex-skip-alists)
         '(("[^\\]\\$" . "[^\\]\\$"))))
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I am indeed using Emacs. Your code snippet, however, produces an "Attempt to modify read-only object" error. Currently I'm using the more general formula `(setq ispell-tex-skip-alists (list (append (car ispell-tex-skip-alists) '(<...>)) (append (cadr ispell-tex-skip-alists) '(<...>))))`, where the `<...>` parts are filled according to the `ispell-tex-skip-alists` format. Also, it seems that `$...$` is skipped by default now and so I'm using `ispell-tex-skip-alists` for other purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Not quite answering the question, but `ispell` (rather than `aspell`) ignores most math environments (with the `-t` option).  To get it to not be confused by new macros, see http://einstein.sc.mahidol.ac.th/~scmal/LaTeX/mspell/index.html .

Answer (score 2):

Regarding your second question, there is a patch for aspell which, among other things, makes it skip inline and displayed math formulae.

The detailed description of the patch is here:

http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/aspell-devel/2011-02/msg00000.html

Unfortunately the patch is not yet in the official repository. I'm using it anyway since I compiled aspell from the source+patch myself. And it works fine.